# Arduino if function does not work as expected

Tags: arduino

I want to set the variable `H_algo` to 0.5 when the heart rate value is in between (45H_algo should be set to 1. And also H_algo = 0 for other heart rate values. But the problem is `H_algo` will not change when the heart rate value exceeds 65 or is below 45 and it stays inside the `if(45<H_val<65)` condition.

This is my code:

```
void loop() {
  H_val = HeartRate();
  // return heart rate value by this function and save to H_val
  Serial.print("Heart rate  ");
  Serial.println(H_val);
  if(45 < H_val < 65) {
    // calculate the H_algo value
    D_time = millis();
    if(D_time - pre1_time >= 1200 ) {
      //check whether heart rate value stay between 45 ad 65 more than 1.2 seconds
      H_algo = 1;
      Serial.print("H_algo  ");
      Serial.println(H_algo);
    } else {
      H_algo = 0.5;
      Serial.print("H_algo  ");
      Serial.println(H_algo);
    }
  } else {
    H_algo = 0;
    pre1_time = millis();
    Serial.print("H_algo  ");
    Serial.println(H_algo);
  }
}
```

This code worked perfectly a few days ago. But when I check it now, it always prints `H_algo = 1` when the heart rate exceeds 65.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is probably here:

```
45 < H_val < 65
```

In C/C++, this expression has a different meaning than you might expect. First, it checks, if 45 is smaller than `H_val`. Then it compares the integral value of the resulting boolean to 65. This is valid C/C++ code but it makes no sense.

What you want to compare is this:

```
45 < H_val && H_val < 65
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear it with an example,

```
int a=10,b=20,c=30;
if(c>b>a)
printf("Yes");
else
printf("No");
```

Output will be `No`.
Relational operator return either `0` or `1` as their output.
So, `c>b>a` can be written as `(c>b)>a`
`c>b`=`30>20` evaluate to be `True`. output will be `1`.
Now, `1>a`=`1>10` evaluate to be `False`.

Comment: @ImeshNirangana Hope so it helps.